# SSH with gitlab and docker executor

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ssh-keys

I am trying to deploy with GitLab pipeline java app on my localvm the runner uses docker and I am getting this error
`aminech@192.168.124.149: Permission denied (publickey,password)`.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
this the YAML file deploy stage
public key is my vm public key
private key is my vm private key
server hostkeys `ssh-keyscan -t rsa 192.168.124.149`

```
deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  before_script:
    - apk add openssh-client
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"  > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  script:
    - ssh  -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no aminech@192.168.124.149  "cd ~/Desktop/javapipline && export IMAGE_TAG=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} && docker-compose up -d"  #
```

I tried the GitLab documentation and it's not helping

Comment: You need to configure SSH on your virtual machine to accept this key for the user you're specifying. Modifying `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't make sense to do on the runner/client. This step would need to be done in advance on the server you're targeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be related to the permissions of the `authorized_keys` file located on the user home folder `~/.ssh/`.

Once you've verified your permissions are correct, you can fix this like so:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

Also a good practice, is to create a user that is dedicated for the deployment task and not use some sudo user for security purpose ( as youre using your personal user `aminech` ). For this you need to :

Create a deployer user :

`$ sudo adduser deployer`

Add the user to the Docker group :

`$ sudo usermod -aG docker deployer`

Set up an SSH key for this user :

```
# Switch to deployer user
$ su deployer

# Generate the key
$ ssh-keygen -b 4096

# Append the public key to the authorized_keys file
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Lastly you need to adjust the permissions to avoid the `Permission denied (publickey,password)` error :

```
# Exit deployer user
$ exit

# Set up the permissions
$ sudo chmod 700 /home/deployer/.ssh
$ sudo chmod 600 /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ sudo chown -R deployer:docker /home/deployer/.ssh
```

By this your you can get ride of the `before_script` section, (dont forget to update the `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable with the private key of the deployer user) and just use :

```
. . .
deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - chmod og= $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deployer@$SERVER_IP "cd ~/Desktop/javapipline && export IMAGE_TAG=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} && docker-compose up -d"
```